# Implementing MVP when you don't own the model?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, mvp

I am working on my first Java GUI and I think I've decided on a MVP architecture (thanks in part to this [great article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html)).

However, a key component of this architecture appears to be that the model notifies the presenter when a change to the model occurs. I'm working with a database API for the model that I don't control. Therefore I have no way of forcing the model to implement any sort of event notification.

In this situation, how is this generally handled? Do I make wrapper classes around the API that implement event notifications? This seems costly and doesn't handle the case when the model is modified outside of the GUI.

---

Update: I think I've found the answer to my own question. What I'm going to be dealing with is a passive model that doesn't participate with the view or presenter at all. I found my answer [here](http://st-www.cs.illinois.edu/users/smarch/st-docs/mvc.html).

Comment: I had to say that MVP it's different architecture that MVC so reading the article the question would be MVC not MVP

Comment: It is different, but the article title is misleading. The article actually ends up describing the MVP architecture.

Comment: Hard to comment without some idea of the API - some kind of wrapper is a possibility; you might need to poll the database (via the API?) to detect changes from outside the GUI.